# Python Dataframe: Create function that makes all values in one column uppercase

Tags: python, function, pandas

I have two python data frames.  I want to make all the values in one column of both data frames uppercase.

The following code works:

```
df_ERA4['reqmnt'] = df_ERA4['reqmnt'].str.upper()
df_ERA5['reqmnt'] = df_ERA5['reqmnt'].str.upper()
```

But when I want to do the same thing in a function it doesn't work:

```
def uppercase(df):
    df['reqmnt'] = df['reqmnt'].str.upper()

df_ERA4 = uppercase(df_ERA4)
df_ERA5 = uppercase(df_ERA5)

df_ERA4.head()
```

Specifically, when I run the above code it gives me the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: You're not returning anything from the function.

Comment: Your function appears to be making changes in place, so calling `uppercase(df)` without assigning anything back, should be enough.

Comment: ah you are right, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function, by default does not return anything. So, by default, it returns `None`. When calling your function, the correct thing to do would be to not assign the return value to anything, since changes are being made in-place.

There are a couple of options now. The first one being: don't return anything, and don't assign anything.

```
def upper(df, col):
    df[col] = df[col].str.upper()

upper(df, 'reqmnt')
```

However, this may not be the best approach (personally, I don't much fancy functions that perform in-place operations). You could, alternatively, have a copy returned via an `assign` call.

```
def upper(df, col):
    return df.assign(**{col : df[col].str.upper()})       

df = upper(df, 'reqmnt')
```

Note that there's a caveat on this side to - `assign` returns a copy, and sometimes, where efficiency/performance are paramount, you don't want to be needlessly making copies of GBs of data. What to use should be decided by a combination of style and need.

Comment: thanks for the including the second option. that's really the way to go, IMO

Comment: @PaulH, Thanks, I agree. I prefer pure functions. Although, sometimes it's alright to modify an object inplace, and return the same object. In this case however, it would depend on the size of your data (since assign returns a copy, you don't want to make wasteful copies of GBs of data, for example). So, when affordable, the second should be the way to go. Otherwise, the first.